# How to run through all the hostnames in the selected file instead of just the first one?

Tags: powershell

My overall goal is to allow the user to have a gui pop-up which lets them select any txt file of choice and to use that file they selected to run the code below the function. As of right now, in a txt file that contains 50 targets, it only runs through the first PC name and completes the code.

What can I do to fix the issue?

```
function Get-Content($initialDirectory) {   
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    if ($initialDirectory) { $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory }
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = 'All files (*.*)|*.*'
    [void] $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
    return $OpenFileDialog.FileName
}

($FilePermissions = Get-Content C:\)



###########################################################################

write-host "Please wait while gathering information..."

$counter = 0


foreach ($computernames in $FilePermissions)           

{
 Write-host "Processing $computernames ($counter/$($FilePermissions.count))" 

IF (Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ComputerName $computernames -Quiet) 
{ 
    $Computersystem = Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computernames -AsJob 
    $videocontroller = Get-WmiObject win32_videocontroller -ComputerName $computernames -AsJob
    $nvidiacontroller = Get-WmiObject win32_videocontroller -ComputerName $computernames -AsJob
    $bioscontroller1 = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computernames
    $bioscontroller2 = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_BIOS -ComputerName $computernames
    $userlogon = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -Property UserName -ComputerName $computernames



    Wait-Job -Job $Computersystem,$videocontroller -Timeout 18 | out-Null 

    $computersystem_output = Receive-Job $Computersystem
    $videocontroller_output = Receive-Job $videocontroller | ? {$_.name -ilike "*Intel*"}
    $nvidiavideocontroller_output = Receive-Job $nvidiacontroller | ? {$_.name -ilike "*NVIDIA*"}




# Creating spreadsheet headers

    $newrow = [Pscustomobject] @{

    Host_name = $computersystem_output.name
    Model_Name = $bioscontroller1.Model
    Serial_Number = $bioscontroller2.SerialNumber
    BIOS_Version = $bioscontroller2.SMBIOSBIOSVersion
    Last_User_Logon = $userlogon.UserName
    Intel_Card = $videocontroller_output.name
    IntelGraphics_Version = $videocontroller_output.DriverVersion
    Nvidia_Card = $nvidiavideocontroller_output.name
    NvidiaGraphics_Version = $nvidiavideocontroller_output.DriverVersion 

    }
     
     $newrow | export-csv -path c:\HostnameData.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
     Remove-Job -job $Computersystem,$videocontroller,$nvidiacontroller -Force
     
     $counter++

    } 


Else 
{
    write-Host "The remote computer " $computernames " is Offline"
}
 
}
```

Comment: your function is just returning the file name not the contents of the file.  So I think you'd want to do `$FilePermissions = Get-Content $FilePermissions`.  Though I don't know the implications of creating your own function called `Get-Content` since that is already a cmdlet.

Comment: That works, thank you! 

Also took your advice on the Get-Content cmdlet and changed my function name.